# mocking get api using axios mock adopter for api testing is throwing response in 400

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-testing, axios-mock-adapter

I am writing a test to mock a get api request with parameters. Even though I'm mocking for successful api response with 200 status the test suit is failing throwing the response in 404. I couldn't figure out what's wrong in my test suit. I'm receiving following here,

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.coerror/AhxbN.png)

this is my mock test for get api. Can someone tell me what's going wrong here.

```
let axiosMock: MockAdapter;
axiosMock = new MockAdapter(instance)
axiosMock
     .onGet('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/patients', {
         params: {
        page: 1,
        sort: 'workspace_patient_id',
        order: 'desc',
        },
    })
     .reply(200, mockResponse);
```

Here is my actual api in react component

```
setFetching(true);
        const response = await getAllPatients(
            paginationModel.page,
            search,
            dataSortModel[0].sort === 'asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc',
            dataSortModel[0].field === 'name' ? 'name' : 'workspace_patient_id',
        );

        if (response.status >= 400 && response.status < 500) {
            console.log(response.status);
            snackbar(response.data.description, 'error');
            return;
        }

        if (response.status >= 500) {
            snackbar('Something went wrong. Please try again.', 'error');
            return;
        }

        if (response.status === 200) {
            console.log('response', response.data);
            const pagedData: IPatientsPaged = response.data;
            const patients: IPatient[] = pagedData.results;
            console.log('patients', patients);

            setMetadata(pagedData.info);
            setRows(
                patients.map((patient) => ({
                    id: patient.id,
                    workspace_patient_id: patient.workspace_patient_id,
                    name: `${patient.first_name} ${patient.last_name}`,
                    contact: patient.contact_number,
                    address: patient.address,
                    email: patient.email,
                    action: () => <></>,
                })),
            );
        }

        setFetching(false);
```

The api is working correctly in react component and rendering all the UI components properly with successful api response. I tried changing await implementation in test suit but it didn't work at all.